# Best practice using Schema.SObjectType

Tags: apex, soql, loop, schema

Wants to know please,

1) Why using the Schema.SObjectType is better than using a SOQL?

2) If using the Schema.SObjectType inside a for loop is a bad Idea...
for example:

```
Id devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Development').getRecordTypeId();
```

I checked and saw that this doesn't affect the SOQL governor Limit - So I guess this is ok to use it inside a for loop?

Comment: Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Development').getRecordTypeId() why are you getting same recordTypeId in loop ? are you changing record type in loop?

Comment: @Manjot Singh, Yes, I need to create accounts with different RC base on some logic.. But it all happens in a Loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling Schema class again and again in loop is not a best practice. It doesn't consume soul limits but can cause

> cpu time limit exceed exception

. So what I normally do is get schema describe result of any object outside loop and then inside loop get which ever value you want to get from that object.

Like for your case I will do

```
Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordtypeMap = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
```

and in loop use `recordtypeMap.get('recordtype').getRecordTypeId();`

In this way I am calling schema class only once and using it at multiple places.

Comment: Ofcourse!
Dont know why I didnt think about it on my own.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: BTW `getRecordTypeInfosByName` is bad practice for looking up a RecordType because it will give different results for different user languages. Use the new `getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName`. Make sure the Apex class is set to at least version 43.